# Javascript - copy file

Tags: javascript, html, copy

This is the script I found via google. And I've edited the file name.

Here it is :

```
<html>
<head>File copy in progress...Don't close this page.</head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    // initialize ActiveXObject and create an object of Scripting.FileSystemObject.  
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  

    // copies a file to another location + overwrites the file if already exits  
    fso.CopyFile("file1.txt", "file2.txt", 1);  


    fso = null;  
</script> 
</html>
```

But it is not copying anything? Actually is it possible in JavaScript to copy a file?

Comment: Which browser are using? This will only work with IE and, I'm guessing, only under certain circumstances.

Comment: firefox,and google chrome @Joe

Comment: Also, you aren't using `<head>` properly. Also, using this synchronously (I don't know how the API works) will make the browser very unhappy.

Comment: `ActiveX` is IE only. `ActiveX objects may present security issues.` is from the Microsoft site :) Though some may argue that IE itself presents security issues...

Comment: well. it is 'possible in JavaScript to copy a file'. But where does this javascript run and what objects can it access, that is the question. As stated, activeX is IE only and will only work with very relaxed trusted source/local settings. I believe FF also has some local file-method stuffed away. And should you talk about w/c script or node.js or... just name one, then it is usually very simple.

Comment: to what/where are you trying to copy files from what/where?

Comment: Also tried it in IE. Same matter

Comment: @puredevotion just learning this. copy in same folder

Comment: @slash-bang i don't think you can do that with js, I also can't really think of a use-case for it. You can copy stuff into the browser (cookie/localstorage/etc.) Then you can use it for whatever you need... Could you present us what you're trying to achieve? (the larger goal/application your building)

Comment: try adding a full path, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx That still works perfect on ie6... just tested it.

Comment: @puredevotion: usecase: everything I programmed in hta has worked from win98 (with a patch even win95) to win7.. You get a simple and uniform environment and virtually full access (file, registry, network) and on top of that a familiar html-interface to create your GUI... learn 2 (ok +css=3) uniform things and be able to translate virtually every task/question to a computer.. what's not to like? (Apparently that everyone can see/modify the source, something that was highly disliked from a corporate point of view), Except ms dropping support in the future

Comment: i did it. but not working. suc as
/home/user/public_html/mycode.html

Comment: read the documentation again. Your slashes are in the wrong direction and when you put them in the right direction, you'd need to escape them for JScript: `"c:\\mydocuments\\letters\\*.doc"`

Comment: Waaaaaiiiit a second.... `/home/user/public_html/` that's not a typical windows path... are you trying to change a file on a (remote) linux server with this (where the html-file is also stored)? (As opposed to local file-access on a windows-machine displaying that html in IE) ? That would kind of change the whole take on uhm.. how everyone has percieved this question up untill now..

Comment: It's not windows. It is linux .

Comment: lol. gotcha. That was totally unclear (especially since the activeX part). Then, no, you can't do this that simple, lemme type up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out in the comments that the asker's goal is the folloing:

Serve a html-page via http(s)
containing javascript that directly copy/modify files on the server that served the html-page.

The answer my friend, is that as far as I'm aware you can't directly (using just client-side javascript from the browser) do that.

For starters, HTTP(S) is not a file-protocol like say.. ftp.

So, ultimately you'd either need to find a way to communicate with a network file protocol (for example ftp) with client-side javascript (I'm unaware of such a general lib, although you can do it in IE, but you'd need some developer-license registry-key's to access full network-features on windows, and you'd still need to do your own wrapping-library (or buy a specific activeX plugin, etc) to do the communication, apart from the rest of your interface).

And the IE-specific code you posted in your answer is not meant to do this either (although it could access windows-shares you have access to).

So clearly, we can kind of forget about that option.

So, since you say you already know how to do these things in php, your next step might be to add a javascript driven/enhanced (think tree-view etc) html-gui that sends commands (post or get) to your php-script that actually copies/modifies the files on your server. Ultimately you are then just recreating a php-file manager (google hint).

If you'd go the node.js way, than this kind of just replaces php and the rest of the methodology is still the same: back-end executes commands and sends results/directory-lists etc. to HTML GUI (possibly via ajax).

You see, there are plenty of more fun things to explore, you are already half way there.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
One might cheat tough, you could download a file (and modify it) and store it in an HTML5 [typed array](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/) and using [http PUT (also supporting delete)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown) storing it on the server again. Now you'd still need to handle security/user-identification... (and there [php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php), json, some server-side handler still kicks-in once again, I'm currently not sure how apaches put-module works once enabled). Using server side includes that you have modified to display a directory-listing and some of this kind of javascript in the header might make a *very crude* file-manager.. kind of.. Not exactly copying...

Comment: Understood that javascript unable to copy file via html. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange example.  First of all, it is not common for an HTML page to interact with the local file system.  I would expect that any modern browser would complain ALOT about this code with warning and setttings requirements.  In addition, it is using an activeX control which should only be available on IE if anywhere.

Maybe this example is about 15 years old?  That would explain a lot.

I wouldn't expect this to work out of the box on any system installed / configured in the last 5 years.

You could change the settings on your system to let it work, but I would not recommend that.  You system would be powned / zombied within minutes.

I think we need to go back to what you are trying to do and why, I suspect that javascript in HTML is not the answer.

---

Based on the comment my suggestion is you work with node.js.  You will learn a lot, have fun, and be working with a technology that is not 15 years out of date.

Go here, have fun:

http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Could be up to 17 years old! `Initial release  1996; 17 years ago` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX

Comment: @NickR - yep... and how soon after that did everyone turn it off.  Not long.

Comment: Actually i am practicing JavaScript

Comment: well.. in a hta it would still work at least up to win7 (who cares about win8..?). PS, there is no javascript in IE, just JScript, ms's quirky not fully true ecmascript implementation (besides the non-standard added stuff). There is a famous pdf floading around from an ms-employe that outlines fundamental differences between jscript and ecmascript at the core level (so Crockford and his quote on wikipedia that jscript is a perfect identical copy is wrong).

Comment: @Hogan, Thanks for that. 
Actually i just try to do something as like php. Means what can i do in php try to do it in JavaScript.

so, i try all things in html.

Comment: @slash-bang - as I said in my answer, the parallel to client side php is node.js not activeX controls in HTML.  Go play with that.

Answer (score 1):

rename your file extension to .hta and double click it.. voila..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: There is just a *little* more to it than you explain in your answer, trust me.